# WPF ComboBox not scrolling with arrow keys

Tags: wpf, xaml, scroll, combobox, arrow-keys

I have a `ComboBox` that is acting strange. It will scroll through the list with the mouse scroll wheel, and jump up/down with <kbd>PgUp</kbd>/<kbd>PgDown</kbd> and <kbd>Home</kbd>/<kbd>End</kbd>, but the arrow keys don't do anything.

```
<ComboBox Name="cboBox"
          SelectionChanged="cboBox_SelectionChanged"
          Margin="5"
          VerticalAlignment="Stretch"
          HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"
```

Other ComboBoxes work fine in other parts of the same program (albeit in a different window). What could be causing the arrow keys to not scroll? The only thing I can think of is that the key presses are being captured and handled elsewhere, but what would cause that?

Comment: try snooping it and seeing if/where the events are being handled? http://snoopwpf.codeplex.com/

Comment: @Tejas - Snoop is an amazing tool. I had no idea it existed. The KeyUp events are being sent to ComboBox, but the KeyDown aren't being fired - not even in the top control. How is KeyDown not being registered?

Comment: well KeyDown is a bubbling event so it would be fired at the lowermost level. PreviewKeyDown is a tunneling event and is fired at the topmost control. Maybe KeyDown is being handled by some control hidden away in the visual tree?